# R data frame constructor converts "-" to "." in column names. Is this preventable?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> test <- data.frame("A-B" = c(0))
> test
  A.B
1   0
```

A-B and A.B mean different things in my application, so I would like to prevent this conversion from happening.  I need to call `as.data.frame(lapply(x, as.numeric))` to convert character data frames into numeric ones, but I can't because it changes my column names.

Comment: See `check.names`: `data.frame("A-B" = c(0), check.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed, I searched a few queries but wasn't able to articulate it so that I got any results.  I'll delete the question in a few minutes if its a duplicate

Comment: No need to delete - this question can be a good signpost to the original question.

Comment: You might try coming up w/ a different name (eg, `A_B`), b/c R doesn't allow mathematical operators (ie, the minus sign) in variable names. (Otherwise, how will R know whether you want the *variable* `A-B` or the *difference* of the variable `A` minus the variable `B`?) In the future you would be able to call `myData[,"A-B"]`, but not `myData$A-B`, for instance.

Comment: @gung, backtics also work, like `test$\`A-B\`` (and regular quotes too, but backticks are preferred).